# Ruby logic and/or chains

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, logic

I am trying to write some validation logic inside of a model for one of my applications. The logic I would like to build in looks like this.

```
def validation
    if this == true or (!that.nil? and those < 1000)
       do something
    else
       do nothing
end
```

Is it possible to do this within a ruby method?

Comment: Of course; it's normal conditional logic. Although you have an assignment in there, not a check for equality. Also, be sure you know the difference between `&&` and `and` etc.

Comment: Excellent! So using parentheses is a valid way of grouping logic?

Comment: Yes! It's actually even recommended...

Comment: Want to post answer so I can mark as solved?

Comment: Watch out: `if this = true` you are setting the variable this to true, test it with `if this == true` ;)

Comment: Yes sorry that was a typo on my part in the question. I will fix. In my code it is == not =

Comment: Rails has plenty of very useful testing methods, not only `.nil?`. Take a look at `.empty?` (Arrays / String), `.present?`, `.any?`, `.blank?`. This kind of methods are very useful to avoid the `!` statement: `if !that.nil?` is equivalent to `if that.present?`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure you can. However, two things to be aware of:

- I suspect you mean `this == true` instead of `this = true`.
- Be very careful when using `and` and `or` instead of `&&` and `||` - they are *not* equivalent. Read up on [operator precedence in ruby](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Ruby_Operator_Precedence), it's subtly different than in other languages such as PHP. You're probably better off sticking with `&&` and `||` for most logical statements and reserving the use of `or` and `and` to control flow, such as `redirect and return`.

So your concrete example should probably look like this:

```
 if this == true || (!that.nil? && those < 1000)
   do something
 else
   do nothing
 end
```

In this particular case, the parentheses are redundant, since `&&` precedes `||`, but they don't hurt, and for anything more complicated, it's good practice to use them to avoid ambiguity and subtle bugs due to a misunderstanding of operator precedence.

Comment: Just to add one more resource that could be useful: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Object.html

Comment: `if this == true` should just be `if this`

Comment: Not the same. `this` could be anything that does not evaluate to `false`, for example a string.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, i would only recommend you to create smaller methods like a method compare each of the attributes and on that method call them.

```
def validation
  if this? or others?
    #do something
  else
    #do nothing
  end
end

private

def others?
  that? and those?
end

def this?
  this == true
end

def that?
  that != nil
end

def those?
  those < 1000
end
```

Comment: What's the point of a method like `this?`? It's it's already a boolean, `if this` does the same thing as `if this?`. I'm a refactoring zealot, but this seems pretty extreme.

Comment: well, i didnt read anywhere about 'this' be only a boolean. So i though it could have another values as nil.

Comment: Same comment then: what does the method give you that the simple expression doesn't?

Comment: IMHO this syntax is more readable, more easy to test and to change the logics in a near future, like compare this with a blank string.

Comment: `this?` doesn't imply a blank string, leading to additional digging through code if the validation doesn't work as expected, whereas `this.present?` is canonical Rails. Similarly, `those?` is mis-named, as it's not a true/false: `those_valid?` or `valid_those?` would be more appropriate. Again: I'm not opposed to refactoring, but I *am* opposed to (a) refactoring before it's necessary, (b) refactoring that is misleading, and (c) refactoring instead of using code canonical to the environment.

Comment: First: I dont want make this a conversation, so that will be my last comment. Second: All i told was to he create smaller methods. The code i posted inst the better solution, was only an attempt to exemplify what i mean. Third: If u have a better solution, just answer.

Comment: My comment on the OP was all I felt was necessary; I missed that they were asking how to tie it in to the validation framework. My concern with your answer was (IMO) its premature over-refactoring when language constructs already do the same. Re-again: I'm not opposed to refactoring, but replacing language with methods in the example shown IMO adds complexity. We can agree to disagree on this.

Comment: Sure we can agree on that. =p